# Calling and custom weather api

Tags: android, weather-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IguMY.png)
I'm new to android developing and i'm about to make weather screen like this
But i don't know how to call and custom the weather api in android studio to make it like this.
Can anyone help me? thanks alot

call api in android studio

Comment: Calling an API and designing a screen are two different things. If you have a clear question about some specific error or problem you can ask and others will answer you. If you search for it there are many tutorials for calling an API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Retrofit or Volley Library For API Calling.
there are many examples, video tutorials are available in Internet.

[Using Volley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7NF-2gtfEU)